# How to convert the results of qint32 to quint8

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, quantization

I am fairly new to quantization in tensorflow. I have the following code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.ops.gen_math_ops import quantized_mat_mul
from tensorflow.python.ops.gen_math_ops import quantized_add

a = tf.constant([1.4,-1.2],shape =[1,2],dtype = tf.float32)
a1 = tf.constant([[1.0],[1.0]],shape = [2,1], dtype=tf.float32)
bias_a = tf.constant([-1.2,1.2],shape=[1,2],dtype = tf.float32)

min_a= tf.reduce_min(a)
max_a= tf.reduce_max(a)
x = tf.quantize(a,min_a,max_a,tf.quint8)

min_a1= tf.reduce_min(a1)
max_a1= tf.reduce_max(a1)
x1 = tf.quantize(a1,min_a1,max_a1,tf.quint8)

min_bias_a= tf.reduce_min(bias_a)
max_bias_a= tf.reduce_max(bias_a)
bias_a_x = tf.quantize(bias_a,min_bias_a,max_bias_a,tf.qint32)

y =tf.matmul(a,a1)
y1 = quantized_mat_mul(x.output,x1.output,x.output_min,x.output_max,x1.output_min,x1.output_max)

o = quantized_add(y1.out,bias_a_x.output,y1.min_out,y1.max_out,bias_a_x.output_min,bias_a_x.output_max)
```

The results of y1 are as follows (qint32,float_max,float_min) where float_max and float_min represent the min and max float values for the quantized int 32 bit output.

However, quantized_add requires inputs in the following format (quint8,float_max,float_min) where float_max and float_min is the max and min float values representing the quantized uint8 result.

I wanted to know if there is a way to convert the results of qint32 to quint8 so that i can feed it into quantized_add function?

Would be really grateful if anyone could help me.

Thanks and Regards,
Abhinav George

Answer (score 0):

You can cast the types from `tf.int32` to `tf.quint8` as follows:

```py
y1_out = tf.cast(y1.out, tf.quint8)
bias_a_x_out = tf.cast(bias_a_x.output, tf.quint8)
```

And then perform `quantized_add` as:

```py
o = quantized_add(y1_out, 
              bias_a_x_out, 
              y1.min_out, 
              y1.max_out, 
              bias_a_x.output_min, 
              bias_a_x.output_max)
```

Comment: Hi, I tried tf.cast but it doesn’t convert to tf.quint8. When I run sess.run to see the results of the casting I get an error message stating dst quint8 is not defined. I shall try again.

Comment: It works for me! Could you please try it again, and let me know whether it works?

Comment: Sure, i have another question may be silly but let’s say I can cast from tf.int32 to tf.uint8 I have to also convert the max and min float values of tf.int32 right ? Any idea on how to do that?

Comment: I tried the following: >>>a = tf.constant(1,tf.int32)                                            >>>a = tf.cast(a,tf.quint8)
>>> sess = tf.Session()
>>> sess.run(a)    I get the error : UnimplementedError (see above for traceback): Cast int32 to quint8 is not supported                                                                                                                                                          
         [[Node: Cast = Cast[DstT=DT_QUINT8, SrcT=DT_INT32, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](Const)]]

Comment: What is your TF version? Also, you may be right, I am not sure whether the min and the max values need to be changed

Comment: I have tensorflow 1.10.0 installed in my system.

Comment: Oh may be I’ve to update the tensorflow version. Thanks though @rvinas